# How to do unsigned integer left shift bit operation in Java 1.8 that matches C#?

Tags: java, c#, numbers, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to port some code from C# to Java and I'm stuck on some low-level bit operations.

Here is an example snippet that I'm trying to figure out how to translate from C# to Java:

```
int shiftAmount = 2;
uint[] tbl = { 1023326899, 1265601397, 3234840308, 1673932182 };
uint[] tblShift = new uint[4];
for (int x = 0; x < tbl.Length; ++x)
{
    tblShift[x] = tbl[x] << shiftAmount;
    Console.WriteLine(tblShift[x]);
}
```

Result:

```
    [0] 4093307596  uint
    [1] 767438292   uint
    [2] 54459344    uint
    [3] 2400761432  uint
```

So far so good.

How do you convert this same thing to **Java**?

So in **Java**, I naively just tried turning all the `uint` to long, it's not correct for all the values:

```
long[] tbl = { 1023326899L, 1265601397L, 3234840308L, 1673932182L };
long[] tblShift = new long[4];
for (int x = 0; x < tbl.length; ++x) {
    tblShift[x] = tbl[x] << shiftAmount;
}
```

You get:

```
0 = 4093307596
1 = 5062405588
2 = 12939361232
3 = 6695728728
```

I'm guessing I have to make an additional shift operation to account for the extra bits in the `long` integer. And probably also have to account for the signed-ness of the integer as well when doing bit operations. But everything I've tried seems to come up wrong.

Does anyone have a guide on how to translate common C++/C# unsigned integer operations to work in Java?

UPDATE: I found a library on Maven central https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOU and it does have some nice unsigned int support, but lacks the bitwise operation libraries. Perhaps I should keep digging looking for an unsigned-bit-operation library.

Comment: I made a mistake in my answer. I have updated it now. Note that I couldn't reproduce your C# results using the same code.

Comment: @Llama this reproduces it: https://rextester.com/BTRG66582

Comment: [Comparison of your question content and your rextester code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8uDx.png).

Comment: i have no idea how that happened. I ran it again from visual studio, pasted. now it looks right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `long` in Java can hold a larger number than `uint` in C# can. `uint` is limited to 4,294,967,295 (0xFFFFFFFF) whereas Java's `long` can hold up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Taking your example of `1265601397L << 2`:

- The C# result is `767438292`
- The Java result is `5062405588` (0x12DBE2DD4)
- If we use a mask of `0xFFFFFFFF`, then we get `0x2DBE2DD4`, which equals `767438292`

Therefore the solution is to use the bitwise AND operator (`&`) to apply the mask and get the C# int-equivalent value:

```java
int shiftAmount = 2;
long[] tbl = { 1023326899L, 1265601397L, 3234840308L, 1673932182L };
long[] tblShift = new long[4];
for (int x = 0; x < tbl.length; ++x) {
    tblShift[x] = (tbl[x] << shiftAmount) & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
}
```

- [Try it online (Java)](https://jdoodle.com/ia/gt3)
- [Fiddle of your C# code](https://rextester.com/CCCP74013)

Results:

| Input | C# output | Java output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1023326899 | 4093307596 | 4093307596 |
| 1265601397 | 767438292 | 767438292 |
| 3234840308 | 54459344 | 54459344 |
| 1673932182 | 2400761432 | 2400761432 |

Comment: Good catch @harold

Comment: OK so here is my PR so far. What would be good edge cases for the unit test? https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOU/pull/24